# ColorPick Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, css, color-picker

In colorpick.js I can able to change the elements color but I am not able to change the border colors present in css. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3xsA.png)

This is the Colorpick Javascript code below:

```
 /* INITIALIZATION COLOURPICKER FOR ELEMENTS
    *********************************************/
    var newColorColorPickElements = $('.ftco-navbar-light, .btn.btn-primary, .bg-light, .sidebar');
    
    $('#pickerelementscolour').colpick({
        layout: 'hex',
        submit: 1,
        colorScheme: 'dark',
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el, bySetColor) {
            $(el).css('border-color', '#' + hex);
            setNewColorUI(hex);
            if (!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
        }
    }).keyup(function () {
        setNewColorUI(this.value);
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
    });
    
    function setNewColorUI(newColor) {
        newColorColorPickElements.css('background', '#' + newColor);
        if (!(/Trident\/7\./).test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            if (localStorage.getItem('elementsColour') != newColor) localStorage.setItem("elementsColour", newColor);
        }
    }
```

please help me resolving this, thank you

Comment: I think we need to see more - the HTML -  and have you checked that there are no errors using your browser's dev tools inspect facility? Are the two different spellings of color/colour correctly used?

Comment: @AHaworth Actually whatever classes I have used that color got changed. But the issue is I am not getting how to change Border-Bottom color as it is given in css.